# How to find out notifications that I closed, Windows 10

Tags: notification-area

**strong text** Many a time I close my notifications without properly looking at it, and after I close it I say, "Oh Shit! That was important"
I can't see them again, so I wanna know

1. How to view the notification?
2. Can it be stored?
3. Will I be able to use the notification as a Jump list to my chat?
   (I mostly close chat notifications, but it doesn't cause a huge problem)

If there is any service like that pls lemme know!

Answer (score 0):

Once the notification has been attended to, it is gone. There is no way to view it again as Windows does not actively store a backup or history of past notifications.

See ['View past notifications in Windows 10'.](https://superuser.com/questions/947947/view-past-notifications-in-windows-10)