# How can I monitor every requests from Windows notifications?

Tags: windows, logging, notifications

I would like to intercept the whole object from the Windows notifications post request coming from remote connection.

A user [Eugene Gagarin](https://superuser.com/a/1525927/230112), have shared a proof of concept about the feasibility to monitor those requests with an answer to the question: [View past notifications in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/1525927/230112).

The app is awesome, but missing some essential data to solve my issue.

Rather than reverse engineering this app, I hope to find a quick answer to close my issue with understanding from scratch this module.

Comment: Have you looked at SYSINTERNAL's `ProcMon`

Comment: @RohitGupta No. I will for sure! Thank you for giving me the first push in my project!