Open Windows notification center pop-up with keyboard (instead of clicking on it)
Example:
You receive an email, and a notification pops up. If you click on it, you are redirected to your mail client in order to read that mail.
I need to do this just with the keyboard. Without installing any third party app.

You  can use the keyboard to direct the mouse cursor: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer-9e0c72c8-b882-7918-8e7b-391fd62adf33, https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/how-to-use-your-keyboard-to-control-the-mouse-pointer-in-windows-10 Also, you might create an app able to read the Notifications SQLite DB at \Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\wpndatabase.db. See https://superuser.com/questions/947947/view-past-notifications-in-windows-10-and-11.
